# Moving the VirtualBox VMs folder

Tags: virtualbox

I accidentally didn't change the target location for a virtual box I created out of an .ova file and now I'm running low on storage on the drive where the VirtualBox VMs folder is located. My question is, is it safe to just cut and paste the folder to a destination on my mass storage drive or do I have to follow any specific rules?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is safe. Your VM's virtual hard disk is the largest file in your VM folder. After moving the files, your existing VM will throw error. You can create a new VM and **when it asks for hard disk, click "use existing.." option and select your vm hard disk file from new location**